# How can i check if a path points to a folder or a file?

Tags: php, zend-framework, file, download

I'm building a small class for my zend application (using MVC). This class receive either a folder path or a file path. If its a folder path, i want to list all the files in that folder to make them downloadable. If its a file i want to make a single link to this file to make it downloadable.

The file/folder i'm pointing to is /zendApplicationName/Public/Models/Subfolder/File.

i tried to check using

```
is_file('pathToFile')
```

and

```
is_dir('pathToFolder')
```

to check the path that i build using

```
APPLICATION_PATH . '..\public' .  $this->_path . 'file.docx'
```

and

```
$this->_baseUrl' .  $this->_path . 'file.docx' // i took the baseURL from Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()
```

I also tried to use the old school php version

```
$protocol = strtolower(substr($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"],0,5))=='https'?'https':'http';
$path = $protocol . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $this->_baseUrl . $this->_path . 'file.docx'
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT :

The problem is that even if the folder and the file exists, both function return false

Comment: What is your question? What happened when you tried `is_file` and `is_dir`?

Comment: Re your edit: Can you show an example of what kind of path you are querying? You are using file paths, not http:// ones, correct? Because is_file() etc. won't work on those

Comment: Your path is wrong and PHP cannot locate the file or directory. Be 100% certain the path exists and is valid. Also try to use constants such as DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR when creating your paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for you comments, both where really useful. They made me recheck my code and the path was wrong

final path output is:

> C:\wamp\www\elul\trunk\elul\application/../public/models/feuilleDeRoute/

using :

> APPLICATION_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
>   . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .
>   'public' . $this->_path;

This way both can be checked, the folder and the file